# $T(d_1) = T(d_2)$ if and only if $d_1(x_0,x_n) \rightarrow 0 <=> d_2(x_0,x_n) \rightarrow 0 $ (for any $(x_n)$)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have following problem:

> Let $d_1, d_2$ - metrics on $X$
>   Show that $T(d_1) = T(d_2)$ **if and only if** for any $x_0, x_1, ... \in X$ if $d_1(x_n,x_0) \rightarrow 0$ then  $d_2(x_n,x_0) \rightarrow 0$ and if $d_2(x_n,x_0) \rightarrow 0$ then  $d_1(x_n,x_0) \rightarrow 0$

I tried to prove that statement:

"=>"

$T(d_1) = T(d_2)$ and $d_1(x_n,x_0) \rightarrow 0$
So lets define $$B_n = B(x_o, d_1(x_0,x_n) + \frac1n) $$ where $B(x,r)$ is an open ball ($\frac1n$ may also be any other  sequence that converges to $0$)

Because topologies are equal then $B_n$ are open in $T(d_2)$ (but $B_n$ may not be balls)
 $B_n$ are open  neighbourhoods of $x_0$ and $dial(B_n) \rightarrow 0$ 
In metrical space there is a ball in every open neighbourhood so there is a sequence of balls $A_n$ (in $d_2$) so that $A_n \contains B_n$ and $r \rightarrow 0$.

**And I am stuck at this point because I don't know hot to show that for big $n$: $x_n \in A_k$.**

"<="

The only idea I have is that closed sets in $d_1$ are the same as in $d_2$ (I think that it would implicate that $T(d_1)= T(d_2)$).

Closures of sets are equal because there is a theorem that $y_0 \in cl(O) <=>$ there exist $(y_n)$ that $y_n \rightarrow y_0$
Since closure of closed sets are equal those sets then any close set is closure of set.
Is it true that it implies that closed sets in $d_1$ are closed in $d_2$?

Comment: So &T& is ... ?

Comment: $T(d)$ is a topology generated by metric $d$